# write a data frame without the Byte ordre Mark in R

Tags: r, dataframe, byte-order-mark

I have a file with french accents in it that I'm readind as:

```
df<-read.csv(paste(dir_in,file_in,sep=''),header=FALSE, sep=';',na.string='NULL',encoding='UTF-8').
```

After some manipulations on df, when saving it as:

```
write.table(df2,paste(dir_out,file_out, sep=''),row.name=F,na="NULL",sep=',',quote=F).
```

I have the Byte order mark "u+feff".

What option can I add in the write.table command to remove it.

I'm using R on windows.

THanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need the accents read the file with the following and your write will work fine: 
df<-read.csv(paste(dir_in,file_in,sep=''), header=FALSE, sep=';', na.string='NULL', fileEncoding='UTF-8-BOM')